# JS Countdown timer stop at 0

Tags: javascript

I have this script. I need it to just stop at 0.

```js
function count() {

  var startTime = document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML;
  var pieces = startTime.split(":");
  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(pieces[0]);
  time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
  time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
  var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
  var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
  document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML = newtime;
  setTimeout(count, 1000);
}
count();
```

```html
<div id='hms'>00:00:05</div>
```

Comment: `var timedif = new Date(0,0,0,pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[2] - 1);`

Answer (score 2):

Stop when string for time is '00:00:00':

```js
function count() {
  var startTime = document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML;

  // exit function immediately
  if(startTime==='00:00:00') return;

  var pieces = startTime.split(":");
  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(pieces[0]);
  time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
  time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
  
  var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
  var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
  document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML = newtime;
  setTimeout(count, 1000);
}
count();
```

```html
<div id="hms">00:00:05</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add a validity condition.

You can try `pieces.some((value) => Number(value) > 0)`

Following is a sample code:

Note I took liberty to rename variables to make it more readable.

```js
function countDown() {
  const container = document.getElementById('hms');
  var startTime = container.innerHTML.trim();
  var [hours, minutes, seconds] = startTime.split(":");
  if ([hours, minutes, seconds].some((value) => Number(value))) {
    var time = new Date();
    time.setHours(hours);
    time.setMinutes(minutes);
    time.setSeconds(seconds);
    var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
    var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
    container.innerHTML = newtime;
    setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
  } else {
    console.log('Ending countdown...')
  }
}
countDown();
```

```html
<div id='hms'>00:00:05</div>
```